# JSONSerialization.jsonObject for complex array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, xcode, swift5

I'm trying to take data return from an API in to an Object. However I am getting errors because the array is complex and not of the same type - it will also differ from the API according to the request made.

```
let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!) as! Dictionary<String, Dictionary<String, String>>
```

The array/data it is being given is as such:

```
[
   'heartbeatStatus' => 'ok',
    'events' => [
       ['id' => '1', 'name' => 'Event'],
       ['id' => '2', 'name' => 'Event 2'],
    ]         
]
```

Is there any simple way of doing this? The questions I have seen on SO so far are either for older versions of Swift (this is Swift 5) or aren't are simply different.

The errors I get are like this (different with the various attempts I have made)

> Could not cast value of type '__NSSingleObjectArrayI' (0x1ed250b30) to
>   'NSDictionary' (0x1ed251378). 2020-04-13 18:52:23.173759+0100
>   *removed app id* [1209:472869] Could not cast value of type
>   '__NSSingleObjectArrayI' (0x1ed250b30) to 'NSDictionary'
>   (0x1ed251378).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use [Codable](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/codable). First define a struct to be your model:

```
struct HeartbeatResponse: Codable { // or whatever

    let heartbeatStatus: String
    let events: [Event]

    struct Event: Codable {

        let id: String
        let name: String

    }

}
```

Then to decode:

```
do {
    if let data = data {
        let heartbeat = JSONDecoder().decode(HeartbeatResponse.self, data)
        // do stuff with heartbeat
    }
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```